# Upload a website on WAMP and modify it

Tags: installation, local-installation

I have a website, all precompiled (modules, plugins, template etc), well zipped in a folder. I want to upload it on WordPress, using WAMP (maybe) so that I can modify it properly.

May you please describe, step by step, how can i do that?

Comment: Please search over the net, you can easily find lot of tutorials on how to do it. [Sample](http://www.wpexplorer.com/install-wordpress-in-windows-wamp/)

Comment: no i disagree, indeed i perfectly installed wordpress on wamp etc..

Comment: what i need to know is: 
having a pre-compled website (made in wordpress), in a zip file, how can i upload it on worpress itself (on a local host) and modify it?

Comment: Well, If you are disagree then good luck ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two components to a web site: files and data.

### Files

WP tends to use simplistic directory structure with all of the files in web root. Getting files in place is a matter of unpacking them to a new location.

### Data

Data is a little more tricky. Typically it would be a dump of MySQL database, but might also be a WP export file. Overall you need to get it into database one way or another (SQL import, WP import, possibly third party tool that automates restore from its backup).

Once you are done you would need to follow the procedure to [change site URL](https://codex.wordpress.org/Changing_The_Site_URL) for a new location.

Without seeing what kind of export you actually have this is about as specific as it gets.